# Access to the path \Start Menu\Programs\Startup is denied

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have created an installer via Visual Studio Installer for a windows form app, that is needed to run at startup.

I am using Visual Studio 2015, and set it up by adding the registry key HKey_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.

Currently it creates a bat file, in the \Start Menu\Programs\Startup, is this correct behavior?

Locally, I have been able to install it and it runs automatically on startup. But on some machines we are having an access is denied issue on startup.

I am not sure if there is something I can do, to prevent this access is denied exception.

Thanks

Comment: Are you installing per-user or per-machine?

Comment: per machine, for all uses of that machine, thanks

Comment: If you're saying that your forms app starts and creates a bat file in the \Startup folder but it fails, then your program requires elevation to put things in the Startup folder and you haven't got that privilege. That could be a UAC setting issue, and also some AV products may prohibit access to Startup locations.